# What is the best practice to include third party ios sdk framework in react-native module library?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to include ios sdk framework in my react-native module library. I turned `always embed swift standard library` to `Yes` in build setting. Everything compiles fine.

Then I include the node module in an app using `npm i react-native-my-framework`, open `sampleapp.xcworkspace` and build in XCode, I get an error `MyFramework/MyFramework-Swift.h` not found. I tried following permutation combinations:

1. Put MyFramework to `Frameworks, Library and Embedded Contents`. and tried some other combination of build settings.
2. Set the `framework search path` in the library project - `$(PROJECT_DIR)/../node_modules/react-native-my-framework/ios/`
3. I manually included `libMyFramework.a` to `Libraries` group.

But I am still facing the same issue. What am I missing here?

Also, `MyFramework` is not on `Cocoa pods`

**Update:**

Now `MyFramework` is available on `Cocoapods`

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Not yet. This project is now in impediment.